# Jupyter notebook with Spark/pyspark kernel behavior after long idle

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebooks seem to be unstable after an idle period long enough to cause the spark executors to have heartbeat timeouts.

Here we see the `executor heartbeat` timeout has been exceeded:

[image]

That behavior is **fine**.  What is **not**: there is no obvious way to get the notebook to recover:  it just **hangs**:

[image]

As can be seen the `*` means the kernel is still thinking it needs to process this cell. This has been the case for 9 minutes now - and the actual exxecution time should be more like 9 *seconds*.

I have tried everything on the menus:

[image]

Attempted:  `restart`  `Reconnect` and even `Shutdown`: ***nothing affects the status of that cell***  - which means the notebook is still "stuck".

Here we see that the `Restart` and the `Shutdown` were received on the `jupyter` server:

[image]

However there is *no effect* on that "stuck" cell ..

Do I simply have to *close* the notebook?  What is the point of all of those menu options in that case ??